# Why mysql lauch on start

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I do my best for explain my problem !

I'm on linux Ubuntu and i use xampp, if i start xampp = Apache Web : running, ProFTPD : running, Mysql: Stopped.

The code error for my sql is :

```
2020-02-28 15:19:42 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 98: Address already in use 2020-02-28 15:19:42 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ? 2020-02-28 15:19:42 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

If i go http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ with 'root' and 'root' is work and i can see my database on the left.

If i watch my netstat : 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1111/mysqld

So i try to stop server with "sudo service mysql stop", now on xampp i restart all and = xampp Apache Web : running, ProFTPD : running, Mysql: running.

Now, go to localhost phpmyadmin but "root" "root" not working and "root" "" work fine but i watch on left and all DB gone.

If i restart my pc and launch xampp = mysql:Stopped and "root" "root" works and on left i can see my db.

I don't understand the problem if someone explain me why mysql running on start and on xampp is stopped ?
Why if start, all db gone and the password is not the same ?

(Sorry i don't have a good english)

EDIT :

Thanks i think is a good way !

But i have a lot of problem all time. I export my Db i got a " mydatabase.sql"

So now i go on xampp mysql and i'm connect but i see this message (pop-up)

[image]

But i'm on adminphp so i go on import and is say me that

[image]

I have develop a website on php but now i follow udemy course for laravel and mysql cause me a lot of trouble i do nothing all this day :(

Comment: I think you have another MySQL Server running on this system

Comment: Both use port 3306, so the first one to start (probably the non-xampp one) will grab that port, when you attempt to start the xampp-mysql it cannot stat as 3306 is already allocated.

Comment: And of course the other mysql has a password on the root user and the xampp one does not

Comment: Yes i thinks is that. But is launch on my computer start and if i stop them with command and restart on xampp (port: 3306) i got this "new" user with no database.. 

So i don't know what i need to do :(

Comment: If you want to use XAMPP, i would backup all your databases on the original version. Only the ones you created. Stop the original version, then start xampp-mysql and restore them. Then change the password for root on the new one. Then reboot so you get the old one again. Stop it, and uninstall it

Comment: Now you should only have the XAMPP version of MySQL, which is probably mariaDB actually :)

Comment: Yes i have mariadb, Sorry but i have a lot of errors ... I have update my post.

But really thanks for you'r help

Comment: The NEW XAMPP version has no password on the root account. So to login to the XAMPP-MySQL leave the password blank

Comment: Yes i do but i search and i need to change that $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = ''; replace $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'password';

A lot of code have to change is dificult ! So now i have no error thanks you ! But my import is still the same like the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two instances / version of MySQL running, looks like you have solved that one,

So you now backing up and moving across your databases.

From your screen shots your getting a few errors, but I can see you you importing your .sql files directly on the server root.

If you your .sql file does not contain a using statement phpmyadmin will not know which database to put the data into. Add the following line to it or move into the database and retry the import.

```
USE databasename;
```

Or if the databases do not exist you can use the following

```
CREATE DATABASE databasename;
USE databasename;
```

substituting databasename for the name of your database.

Comment: Yes i say in comment i'm stupid and on my import i do not select a database. The import is table not db so it's works ;)
Thanks, but now i don't now where the mysql lauch alone on my pc start so i don't know who can i delete him.

If i do that : https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql

I'm afraid is delete my old sql and my new sql i have setup for xampp

Comment: You xampp will be maria and i am guessing the other one is mysql becuase you do sudo service mysql stop, you could prove this by looking at the services on the machine or running sudo service mariadb stop when xampp services are running. Uninstalling mysql will not unistall mariadb, but you have all your backups now anyway.

Comment: I follow the command line on the link. So now i got one mysql (xampp) all is nice.

Thanks a lot guys and have a great day !